# Monaco Editor show programming language and code number lines

Tags: monaco-editor

Is There any way to add the name of the programming language on top of the code? as in the picture, and also add the numbers of the line code. ?

here is the api, but I dont find anything about this info.

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.IEditorOptions.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that this functionality exists, but there is a codelens feature, which looks like this:

[image: codelens]

There is a lot of useful info on monaco editor playground, here is the [codelens](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.37.0-dev.20230329#XQAAAAJVAwAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMpUO-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWS9TrQEnwCrP6UHhcnAub7NsHdDWJ95Ldgbdym8OPZNG-iOFX6J5GjewZis7sdX7c_7u5Z1gC11Cm-AsDgbLILVY332YN1kf0wxv1Y5c9TQ3l8SbA4Q-Y9wpEQcV3h-upSdJtaW5i0Lc2mOmn0K4i7j_NdM0EQTRkL2e5gpMGDUw_tgthk8kx95pP_3v9J0ht6zUD8Rkc3qfvl2ZizaUuLnYaY5MN3AyVb2EVeAlh-QN7X4Rj9Siqy6hNghrhPW0sqtAUJwuAxSUvaMYZk-rmq_usNF-kpHU_ANl7fPS0jxixMhIOF0_380NTFgiqH3pMp-SOAJ3gG6YKwlx3estqfDRJ1qic3Opgu9fcwYfXlW6kSIrcxeAu78HzHxRVAVixI11HeTb8nHxOFnFzk5Tm8Ky4ZjQdBbB4LmaaCbwJ6zjZtQ7ntH6tIahQBOGz78g1mBU1vIrkFmmqwHWIurkMPqyn-HGOjtDQ0gRo7i_Ey4SuAGQB1UQc1WkUQqPIrTy55AGfRDJIJ5LjlVjM966vwSgHmt-aebr7TsMC_8sgRrs) example.

Line numbers should be added by default, but if they aren't then instantiate the editor with `lineNumbers: 'on'`.

Here is the complete example:

```js
let lang = 'SQL';
monaco.languages.register({ id: lang });

let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "some text here\nit's a second line",
    language: lang,
    lineNumbers: 'on',
});

monaco.languages.registerCodeLensProvider(lang, {
    provideCodeLenses: function (model, token) {
        return {
            lenses: [
                {
                    range: {
                        startLineNumber: 1,
                        startColumn: 1,
                        endLineNumber: 2,
                        endColumn: 1,
                    },
                    id: "language",
                    command: {
                        id: commandId,
                        title: lang,
                    },
                },
            ],
            dispose: () => {},
        };
    },
    resolveCodeLens: function (model, codeLens, token) {
        return codeLens;
    },
});

var commandId = editor.addCommand(
    0,
    function () {
        // this function is executed upon clicking on codelens
    },
    ""
);
```